# cakephp installation htaccess issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I'm trying to install CakePHP in `www.domain.com/demo/realestate` I changed `.htaccess` in root, app,webroot with ref from [cakebook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html), [S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/) and other websites. Most of them produced either `500` error or shown a blank page or `404` error.

My `.htaccess` code in each of those files are:
 
 --in root--

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /demo/realestate
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

--in app--

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

--in webroot--

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also tried to delete all `.htaccess` and write `Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));` in `app/config/core.php`  as per a suggestion in [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html) but then it started taking demo as controller name and realestate as function name.

I request you to guide me to set it up!

Comment: this is hosted on godaddy server

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change in htaccess if you want to install cakephp in www.domain.com/demo/realestate. Just copy all cakephp files and folders in realestate folder with default htaccess and it'll work.